# Is my SSD drive dying?

Tags: linux, ssd

Last day i've found in the dmesg log and i'm quite worried because it's a brand new drive.

What do you think ?

```
[1681380.516688] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[1681380.517264] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[1681380.518303] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[1681380.518309] ata1: EH complete
[1681380.518767] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[1681380.518994] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[1681380.519523] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[1681380.520071] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:18:1e:81/00:00:02:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[1681380.520071]          res 41/40:00:18:1e:81/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[1681380.521159] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[1681380.521692] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[1681380.522697] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[1681380.522704] ata1: EH complete
[1681380.523166] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[1681380.523400] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[1681380.523861] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[1681380.524369] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:18:1e:81/00:00:02:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[1681380.524370]          res 41/40:00:18:1e:81/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[1681380.525382] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[1681380.525873] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[1681380.526845] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[1681380.526852] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[1681380.526854] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[1681380.526858] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[1681380.526863] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[1681380.526865]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00
[1681380.526874]         02 81 1e 18
[1681380.526878] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[1681380.526883] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 02 81 1e 18 00 00 08 00
[1681380.526892] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 42016280
[1681380.527102] ata1: EH complete
[1681380.527104] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_find_entry: inode #1311883: (comm updatedb.mlocat) reading directory lblock 0
[1681380.527107] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[1681380.528161] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Do a backup immediately and replace it.

Comment: I would like to add "always backup regularly, don't wait until your drive(s) starts to act up because that might be way too late" - if a drive that's misbehaving have you worried - you should rethink your personal backup strategy so you aren't worried ^^

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Check the SMART status to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

As it is a brand new drive, use the warranty to get a replacement.

Otherwise here is how to trigger a reallocation of a bad block:

Find the physical sector(s) causing trouble, here it is shown as being sector 42016280 in this dmesg line:

```
end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 42016280
```

Confirm it is the one by attempting to read it with hdparm:

```
hdparm --read-sector 42016280 /dev/sda
```

If it is indeed the one, you'll get an Input/Output error.
Trigger the reallocation by writing to this sector with hdparm:

```
hdparm --write-sector 42016280 --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing /dev/sda
```

Try reading the sector again and it should come up as filled with zeros.

Alternatively, you can try your luck with invoking badblocks through e2fsck:

```
e2fsck -c /dev/sda
```

This command runs a non-destructive read test which sometimes is enough to fix some read error issues.

Lastly check the manufacturer support for specific issues, for example crucial m4 ssd have a hard time with unexpected power loss which could cause faulty behavior and failure to attempt to auto reallocate bad sectors. Crucial support recommends to do a [power cycle](http://forums.crucial.com/t5/Crucial-SSDs/Why-did-my-SSD-quot-disappear-quot-from-my-system/ta-p/65215)

Credit goes to [Bas' Blog](http://www.sj-vs.net/forcing-a-hard-disk-to-reallocate-bad-sectors/)

-edit-
If all else failed, one can attempt to restore the ssd to factory default through the ata secure erase command as explained on the arch wiki SSD memory cell clearing article (search for it, I can't link it due to posting as guest)